# PHP MySqli Multiple query & while in one page - help to simplifying code

Tags: php, mysql, html, mysqli

I'm following the official PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

So far I have my code as follows, but I'm not sure if I'm doing the right thing, since I'm using on the same page many "query" and "while", I wondered if the possibility of putting at the beginning of the code all PHP and within the HTML call the variables with an "echo" to not have to go by opening and closing PHP all the time, could help me simplify this code to enterder but as it is right or whether this is "good" within normal continue. Thanks in advance!

```
<?php 
  require_once("inc/header.php");

  $connect = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pass", "db_name");
  if ($connect->connect_errno) {
    printf("Error: %s", $connect->connect_error);
    exit();
  }
?>
<!-- *************** show products *************** -->
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">    
<?php
  $query = "SELECT * FROM product";
  if ($result = $connect->query($query)) {
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
?>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
   <div class="thumbnail">
    <a href="product.php?id=<?php echo $row['product_id']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $row['product_img']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $row['product_name']; ?>"></a>
     <div class="caption">
      <a href="product.php?id=<?php echo $row['product_id']; ?>"><h6 class="truncate"><?php echo $row['product_name']; ?></h6></a>
      <h5><?php echo "$".$row['product_price']; ?></h5>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>    
<?php
  }
  $result->free();
  }
?>
 </div>
</div>

<!-- *************** Latest 10 products... *************** -->
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">    
<?php
  $query = "SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY product_id DESC LIMIT 10";
  if ($result = $connect->query($query)) {
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
?>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
   <div class="thumbnail">
    <a href="product.php?id=<?php echo $row['product_id']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $row['product_img']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $row['product_name']; ?>"></a>
     <div class="caption">
      <a href="product.php?id=<?php echo $row['product_id']; ?>"><h6 class="truncate"><?php echo $row['product_name']; ?></h6></a>
      <h5><?php echo "$".$row['product_price']; ?></h5>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>    
<?php
  }
  $result->free();
  }
?>
 </div>
</div>

<!-- *************** Show the categories list... *************** -->
<?php
  $query = "SELECT * FROM categories";
  if ($result = $connect->query($query)) {
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  ?>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="categories.php?id=<?php echo $row['categories_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['categories_name']; ?></a></li>
  </ul>    
  <?php
  }
  $result->free();
  }
  $connect->close();
?>

<?php require_once("inc/footer.php");?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest use a library called meekrodb, once loaded, you can do queries like this

```
$news = DB::query("SELECT id,title WHERE title = %s","Title you want");
foreach ($news as $new) {
echo $new["title"];
}
```

It's perfect to do too many queries on one page. You can download legally and free from [MeekroDB.com](http://meekro.com/)

Comment: Perfect, now I get to read, that would be a great help to simplify the code!

Comment: I have a proposal watching this time and I loved it, makes things much easier, I'm sure implementare in my project.

Comment: Great!  Of course, since I discovered that library, the code is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing technically wrong with what you are doing.  You could save yourself a database query by trying to combine the 2 queries against your 'product' table, but that's not a problem unless your site or your database are busy.

If you want to "simplify" your calls you could turn then into functions and use the results from those functions to draw the HTML, but then you would have to pull them into memory and run over an array.

Comment: I am happy to read this, I wonder where I could find documentation on functions, as it could try something new (I like to have as short as possible and ordered code), but at least I can continue with this method, you could give me an example of functions if I do not take you long?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you're on the right way to write the beautiful code. What you're asking about is called [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).

The idea is to separate the logic and the interface. There is a lot of production ready template engines for PHP, like Smarty or Twig. It's up to you to learn more about them and decide, which one better suits your needs. Or even to create your own engine.

They all are pretty simple. You create the code, that collects all the data needed on page, and then pass this data to the template engine, which displays it according to the template selected, written with simplified template engine syntax. Something like:

```
<?php 

  require_once("template_engine.php");
  require_once("inc/header.php");

  $connect = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pass", "db_name");
  if ($connect->connect_errno) {
    printf("Error: %s", $connect->connect_error);
    exit();
  }

  $products = array();
  $query = "SELECT * FROM product";
  if ($result = $connect->query($query)) {
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $products[] = $row;
  }

  $latest = array();
  $query = "SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY product_id DESC LIMIT 10";
  if ($result = $connect->query($query)) {
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $latest[] = $row;
  }

  $categories = array();
  $query = "SELECT * FROM categories";
  if ($result = $connect->query($query)) {
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $categories[] = $row;
  }

  echo $parser->parse_my_template("templatename.tpl", array(
      "products" => $products,
      "latest" => $latest,
      "categories" => $categories
    ));
?>
```

And separate file templatename.tpl (for example, in twigg syntax):

```
  ...

  {% for product in products %}
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
   <div class="thumbnail">
    <a href="product.php?id={{ product.id }}"><img src="{{ product.image }}" alt="{{ product.name }}"></a>
     <div class="caption">
      <a href="product.php?id={{ product.id }}"><h6 class="truncate">{{ product.name }}</h6></a>
      <h5>{{ product.price }}</h5>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>    
  {% endfor %}

  .....
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, for now and I'm starting to learn the basics! Pensare and after learning a framework haha

Comment: I was glad to see this code, but does not work without installing smarty or something right? Smarty had seen but for now I find it very difficult, it would be great to use this code or something similar without relying on other tools.

Comment: Smarty is not the only variant here. Just google "php template engine" - there are hundreds of them.

Comment: But if you don't want to use any other tools at all - there is no other way than to open and close php tags. At least you can put all echoing code to the bottom the script and use <?php foreach($products as $product) { ?> ... <? echo $product['image'] ?> .... <? } ?> to output the arrays of data. This would look a bit cleaner. But only a bit...

Comment: I understand, thank you very much for the clarification! Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Your 'categories' segment appears to be writing a new ul tag for each item?
You should move the ul tags to outside of that segment of php.

Comment: If it is correct, try to make the most basic example but do not take that into account, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your code, but if you want to simplify it, you can do it a little bit, since you are doing almost same task on 2 different queries (show products and latest 10 products). You can save these queries in string array, start a foreach loop and merge code.

this will look like:

```
<?php
$ProductQueries = array("SELECT * FROM product", "SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY product_id DESC LIMIT 10");

foreach ($ProductQueries as $ProductQuery)
{
?>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">    
<?php
  $query = $ProductQuery;
  if ($result = $connect->query($query)) {
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
?>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
   <div class="thumbnail">
    <a href="product.php?id=<?php echo $row['product_id']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $row['product_img']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $row['product_name']; ?>"></a>
     <div class="caption">
      <a href="product.php?id=<?php echo $row['product_id']; ?>"><h6 class="truncate"><?php echo $row['product_name']; ?></h6></a>
      <h5><?php echo "$".$row['product_price']; ?></h5>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>    
<?php
}
$result->free();
}
?>
 </div>
</div>
<?
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I'm looking at my learner, now I'll get to read about what you propose to master new things! Thanks for your time!

Comment: pleasure helping you, if this is the answer of your question, please mark this as accepted answer :)

Comment: Sure, I'm reading all the answers to know what you could implement! Regards!